# How to prevent css animation to be stopped when class removed

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations

I have a grid.
I need to highlight row with orange color on 3 seconds when I get update message from backend.
When I get update, I add css class 'highlight' to my row and play my animation.

```css
.highlight {
  animation-name: highlight;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes highlight {
  0% {
    background-color: orange;
  }

  99.99% {
    background-color: orange;
  }
}
```

For some reasons of message flow in application I need to remove highlight class before the 3 seconds ends and my animation will stop working. I expect that my animation will be playing to the end of 3 seconds.

How to make my animation play to the end even if I removed the class highlight?

Comment: How about setting a timeout of 3 seconds using `setTimeout(() => {// remove class actions }, 3000)`?

Comment: Yes, I think I can try something like this using the redux-saga. I try to keep it simple and use css for it, but not additional logic.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to add a data- attribute to the element then add an animationend event listener to it so that when the animation finishes, the event listener knows to remove the class. See example below.

```js
document.getElementById('clicky').addEventListener('click', () => {
  const element=document.querySelector('.highlight');
  element.setAttribute('data-remove-class', 'highlight');
  element.innerHTML='Will remove class at finish of animation';
});

document.querySelector('.highlight').addEventListener('animationend', (e) => {
  const removeClass = e.target.getAttribute('data-remove-class');
  if (removeClass == 'highlight') {
    e.target.classList.remove(removeClass);
    e.target.removeAttribute('data-remove-class');
    e.target.innerHTML='Class removed!';
  }
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  animation-name: highlight;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes highlight {
  0% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  99.99% {
    background-color: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='highlight'>Animating!</div>
<button id='clicky'>Remove Class</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, we don't work directly with document  in application, we are using only grid library api. I thought may be there is some pure css solution for this case. Thank you very much, I think your example can be good solution for other cases.

Comment: So what are all the constraints? If you can add a class, can you add to an inline style attribute too?

Comment: I add class by using interface of grid library
classRules = {
     'highlight-row': data => data.toHighlight
} 
ag-grid library https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grid-options/#reference-styling-rowClassRules

Answer (score 0):

If you take off the animation class, it will stop the animation, logically. So what you're asking is not possible with a CSS keyframe animation class. If you want to continue the animation, why not just leave it on the element? Why do you have to take it off? Can't you use an alternative, e.g. different class, attribute, etc?

Comment: It is because of grid library and message flow in application. I get big amount of messages with a big list of updates to row. So, the real situation is, what in moment when I need to highlight the row I get message with highlight true (adding css class highlight), and for example after 0.3 second I get one more message with another updates for this row, where highlight is false already  (because the moment to start was 0.3 seconds before), and my class removing automatically.